# MTproto server works inefficiently after a short time

Tags: docker, docker-compose, telegram, digital-ocean, mtproto

I set up a mtproto server on a digitalocean droplet but after a few hours it starts to get slow and connect and disconnect continuously although the only person is using it is me.
I used [iShift](https://github.com/iShift/docker-compose-mtproxy) to set up my server and I also tried [telegrammessenger/proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/telegrammessenger/proxy/) but the result is the same.

Here are some more info:
digitalocean droplet:5$/mo, ubuntu 14.04
port:1050
number of workers:16

Have any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Do you have any logs during slowness? Did you check resources on the server? Maybe you get out of RAM or your CPU usage goes high...

Comment: @AliHashemi yes I checked the resources including CPU,RAM,Bandwidth and none of them is overbusy and there are many free resources.